# How many illegal moves are allowed in Classical, Rapid & Blitz?

Tags: rules, fide, blitz, illegal-move, rapid

As of Jan-2024, I see that **2 illegal** moves are allowed in chess and the 3rd one results in a lose of the game by the one who made those.

> [**FIDE 7.4b**](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf) After the action taken under Article 7.4.a, for the first two illegal moves by a player the arbiter shall give two minutes extra time to his opponent in each instance; **for a third illegal move by the same player, the arbiter shall declare the game lost by this player**. However, the game is drawn if the position is such that the opponent cannot
> checkmate the player’s king by any possible series of legal moves.

How many illegal moves are allowed for each format as per FIDE?

Comment: Your link is actually to an older version of the Laws of Chess. It says "The English text is the authentic version of the Laws of Chess, which was adopted at the 79th FIDE Congress at Dresden (Germany), November 2008, coming into force on 1 July 2009." It's been changed multiple times since then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are referencing a very old version of the FIDE Laws of Chess. The latest version, [FIDE Laws of Chess taking effect from 1 January 2023](https://FIDE%20Laws%20of%20Chess%20taking%20effect%20from%201%20January%202023), says this for the classical format:

> 7.5.5    After the action taken under Article 7.5.1, 7.5.2, 7.5.3 or 7.5.4 for the first completed illegal move by a player, the arbiter shall give two minutes extra time to his/her opponent; for the second completed illegal move by the same player the arbiter shall declare the game lost by this player. However, the game is drawn if the position is such that the opponent cannot checkmate the player’s king by any possible series of legal moves.

and this is for rapid and blitz:

> A.3    The penalties mentioned in Articles 7 and 9 of the Competitive Rules of Play shall be one minute instead of two minutes.
>
> A.5.2    If the arbiter observes an action taken under Article 7.5.1, 7.5.2, 7.5.3 or 7.5.4, he/she shall act according to Article 7.5.5, provided the opponent has not made his/her next move.

In other words **for all three time controls, a second illegal moves loses the game**. For standard the penalty for a first illegal move is to give the opponent an additional 2 minutes on the clock and in rapid and blitz, one minute on the clock.

Comment: A recent USCF-rated Blitz tournament had a single illegal move resulting in a loss (if correctly claimed by opponent before they made a move). Event was not FIDE rated.